# How do I set up Facebook comments on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I have tried for a month to set up Facebook comments on my site. I want the comment box on my post pages. Also, I want the social buttons which seem to be there sometimes. What file do I place the JavaScript SDK code on, in my PHP or CSS (or is it pasted into each post page)? Then do I cut and past the plugin code into each page I want it to be available, or just in one theme file? I'm lost in this sense and no one seems to be able to give me an answer.

Comment: Can you post examples of things you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

All of the information you will need is on the [Facebook developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)! If you are using Wordpress you may easily implement Facebook comments by installing the official [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/).